# Elastica with FOS : ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, elastica, foselasticabundle

In my symfony2 / doctrine 2 application, I get an error when running fos:elastica:populate :

> [Elastica\Exception\Bulk\ResponseException]
>   Error in one or more bulk request actions:
>   index: /foodmeup/offer/4 caused MapperParsingException[failed to parse
>   [res     ponsibilities]]; nested:
>   ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown prop     erty [0]];

My config is the following, I have set type: string to responsibilities which is actually a doctrine json array:

```
offer:
    mappings:
        name: { type: string, boost: 10}
        content: { type: string }
        responsibilities: { type: string }
        skills:
            type: "nested"
            properties:
                name: { type: string }
        contractType:
            type: "nested"
            properties:
                name: { type: string }
        position:
            type: "nested"
            properties:
                name: { type: string, boost: 10 }
```

And my entity mapping :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=false)
 */
protected $responsibilities = array();
```

What can I do to resolve this ? I have tried with "~" instead of "string" but the same problem arises and when I just remove the config line for responsibilities, it works well.

Thanks !

Comment: maybe because your responsibilities is an array and cannot be configured as string in the mapping , check if there is array type in the bundle

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use some transformers as your data are not of the same types.
I really recommend you to read this article:
http://obtao.com/blog/2014/05/advanced-indexing-with-elasticsearch-foselasticabundle/

Comment: nice, I'll try that out!